# Angular-ui-router breaks when uglified with gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, gulp

I have the following simple angular.js app, following best practices outlined [here](http://toddmotto.com/opinionated-angular-js-styleguide-for-teams).

```
angular
  .module('myApp', ['ui.router']);

(function() {
    function routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404");

        $stateProvider
            .state('createCluster', {
                url: '/create-cluster',
                templateUrl: 'templates/create-cluster.html'
            })
    }

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .config(routes);
})();
```

I am using **gulp** to concat all JavaScript files, including `angular-ui-router.js` and run everything through `uglify` after. When I uglify though, I am getting:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: e

When I remove the uglification, everything works. How can I get uglification to not break **ui-router**?

Here is my `gulp` task:

```
gulp.task('uglify-js', function () {
  gulp.src(['client/js/libraries/**/*.js', 'client/js/source/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app'))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(rename({ extname: ".min.js" }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('client/js'))'
});
```

Comment: Have you read the section on minification in the post that you linked to? The problem is that the minification changes the names of the things you inject.

Comment: change `.config(routes);` to `.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', routes]);` so you'll tell Angular which dependencies to inject for each parameter. In that way, you will not lose the parameter matching when you minify

Comment: Shouldn't `.pipe(ngAnnotate())` does this for me? See my **grunt** file.

Comment: @Justin by grunt you mean gulp, right?

Answer (score 16):

One simple thing to get this working without changing all your code is to set the `mangle` option of `uglify` to false like so :

```
gulp.task('uglify-js', function() {
  gulp.src(['client/js/libraries/**/*.js', 'client/js/source/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('app'))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify({ mangle: false }))
    .pipe(rename({ extname: '.min.js' }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('client/js'));
});
```

That keeps the names so you will not have injections problems.

Comment: That will "fix" the problem, but will make the minification process less useful.

Comment: I know, but quoting the OP : "How can I get uglification to not break ui-router?"

Comment: @Aperçu Thanks it did help me; Too bad it breaks ui-router;; this will need to investigate :p gonna write an issue about it

Comment: @DmitriyZ Glad that helped ;)

Answer (score 4):

You should use [ngannotate](https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate). This while preprocess your angular code to make it safe for uglify/minification. Ngannotate adds dependency annotations so the minifier doesn't break your dependency injection.

The [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05) provides a note on this:

> Since Angular infers the controller's dependencies from the names of arguments to the controller's constructor function, if you were to minify the JavaScript code for PhoneListCtrl controller, all of its function arguments would be minified as well, and the dependency injector would not be able to identify services correctly. We can overcome this problem by annotating the function with the names of the dependencies, provided as strings, which will not get minified.

Ngannotate does this process for you which keeps your code cleaner.

[Ngmin](https://github.com/btford/ngmin) is now deprecated and the github advises to use ngannotate. It is also faster than ngmin.

Comment: +1, the best practices he references says to do exactly this :)

Comment: I am already doing this in my **grunt** file: `.pipe(ngAnnotate())`

Comment: @Justin check the docs for ng-annotate. It uses pattern matching to know where to fix up the injections, and it's likely your syntax is not being matched to any of its known patterns.

Comment: Try the suggestion to set mangle option to false on uglify. This is also what I do.

Comment: @cnaut see my solution of using the hint `@ngInject` for **gulp** `ngAnnotate`. Clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

See the code being generated. A problem when minifying AngularJS is that the dependency injection is based on parameter names, and as such will break when minified.

For instance, this line

```
function routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
```

may end up looking like

```
function routes(a, b) {
```

and then Angular won't know which dependency to inject, and you will get the `Unknown provider` error.

To fix that, you can use the [array syntax](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di) (see: Inline Array Annotation) instead.

```
['$dependencyA', '$dependencyB', function($dependencyA, $dependencyB)
```

because minified that will look like

```
['$dependencyA', '$dependencyB', function(a, b)
```

and then Angular knows what to do.

In your case, it will be something like

```
.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', routes]);
```

Comment: Should'nt `.pipe(ngAnnotate())` in my **grunt** file do this.

Comment: @Justin yeah, but some cases it won't work. Then the array syntax is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this so that minification don't mess up the injection:

```
var routes = function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404");

    $stateProvider
        .state('createCluster', {
            url: '/create-cluster',
            templateUrl: 'templates/create-cluster.html'
        })
};

routes.$inject = ['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider'];

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(routes);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the solution.

Or, even better than manually specifying the dependancies using `$inject`, use the built in `@ngInject` helper in **gulp** `ngAnnotate`.

```
angular
    .module('myApp', [
        'ui.router'
    ]);

(function() {
    /**
     * @ngInject
     */
    function routes($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/404");

        $stateProvider
            .state('createCluster', {
                url: '/create-cluster',
                templateUrl: 'templates/create-cluster.html'
            })
    }

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .config(routes);
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget your `@ngInject` comment above the function, I'm working on getting auto-function reference landed in a future version of ng-annotate, if you could join and +1 here that'd be awesome: https://github.com/olov/ng-annotate/issues/57